# Interpret DBT2 results

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm testing experimental storage (so I expect the numbers to be bad / far off).

I ran the test on the experimental storage and got this:

```
                         Response Time (s)
 Transaction      %    Average :    90th %        Total        Rollbacks      %
------------  -----  ---------------------  -----------  ---------------  -----
    Delivery   3.01     42.087 :    55.219           11                0   0.00
   New Order  37.70     11.001 :     7.547          138                2   1.45
Order Status   2.19      0.157 :     0.619            8                0   0.00
     Payment  35.79      4.602 :     5.585          131                0   0.00
 Stock Level   1.37      0.777 :     1.675            5                0   0.00

-0.64 new-order transactions per minute (NOTPM)
-212.7 minute duration
73 total unknown errors
2.00 rollback transactions
-1 second(s) ramping up
```

And then I ran the same test on Azure 30 GB HDD (not a powerhouse either...) and got this:

```
                         Response Time (s)
 Transaction      %    Average :    90th %        Total        Rollbacks      %
------------  -----  ---------------------  -----------  ---------------  -----
    Delivery   2.31      0.068 :     0.096           10                0   0.00
   New Order  47.45      0.026 :     0.033          205                1   0.49
Order Status   3.94      0.002 :     0.003           17                0   0.00
     Payment  43.98      0.011 :     0.018          190                0   0.00
 Stock Level   2.31      0.005 :     0.009           10                0   0.00

41.07 new-order transactions per minute (NOTPM)
5.0 minute duration
0 total unknown errors
1.00 rollback transactions
0 second(s) ramping up
```

But I don't understand what am I seeing in any of the columns (well, sans the name of a transaction).  Can anyone kindly explain what do they show?

I'll give you my guesses, just to show I tried to solve the mystery :)

- `%` relative portion of time the transactions of this type spent cumulatively.
- `Average` must be the average latency (i.e. number of seconds it took for an average transaction to go through).
- `90 %` The same as above, but for the 10% of the worst transactions in this group.
- `Total` is the number of transactions performed.
- `Rollbacks` is the number of rollbacks per *all* (?) transactions in this group.

---

My Perl skills are nonexistent, so I wouldn't be able to edit the `mix_analyzer.pl` to make it work with these data.  It's kind of funny how it went into negative space, though it would've been also useful if it worked even with such slow devices...

PS. This is tagged "MySQL" because the test is endorsed by MySQL, and the actual database under test was MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` would be a percentage of number of transactions (check against Total column).

90th is a percentiles - 90% of transactions finished in this time (so maximum rather than average).

Your dodgy negative results could be result of running `ntpdate` as a cron job or some other extreme time adjustment so discard those results and try again.

Comment: So, is my assumption about the meaning of "Average" correct? Thanks for the info on "90%". And this isn't a result of NTP server running. The results are consistent across multiple runs. Just an error in Perl script, I wish I could understand it. The mix.log reports a bunch of errors, which leads me to conclude that it might be the cause for the calculation to produce negative times.

Comment: Average and Total having the fairly obvious meanings you've mentioned are correct. Looking at the result it seems to be only the time figure that is incorrect (hence my assumption). Given it looks like a fixed 5 minute test 138/5 is the new orders per minute benchmark and you don't need to fix the perl. BTW these figures look low, are there indexes on columns? From memory some early benchmarks don't have any.

Comment: The tables were created by the test itself, I'm not sure if it creates indexes or not, but it's not crucial for the test I need: I need to compare the performance of a known well-behaving device to an experimental one. I don't need to get the best performance.